# sed address mode

Tags: sed

i would like to change the 'line' to 'row' only at the entry that has omg in front.  Do you have any idea how to do it?

```
pluto% cat test
omg this is 1st line
omg this is 2nd line
omg this is 3rd line
this is 4th line
omg this is 5th line
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
sed -e '/^omg/s/line/row/'
```